# How to locate element in Protractor by placeholder

Tags: protractor

How to locate element in Protractor by placeholder. I tried with $('[placeholder=Article name]').click();

it shows an error " Failed: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified"`

```html
<input _ngcontent-c30="" class="mat-input-element mat-form-field-autofill-control ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-touched" matinput="" required="" maxlength="80" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9 ]{1,80}" id="mat-input-51" placeholder="Article name" aria-invalid="true" aria-required="true" aria-describedby="mat-error-0">
```

`

Comment: you need to use single/double quote to wrap the value of placeholder as this: `$('[placeholder="Article name"]').click()`

Comment: it worked! thanks a ton!